# Javascript will not run properly

Tags: pages, jquery, javascript

I have [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/CxnQA/2/) which runs perfectly on jsFiddle. When I try to run that code on my self-hosted WordPress site, however, it will not run. (The code is exactly the same on my page, except that I added `<script type="text/javascript" src="/files/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>` before the Javascript on the page.) The Javascript is directly in the Text tab of my page, JS first followed by the HTML. The form loads properly, but clicking the "Add Row" button does nothing.

I had this issue on another page on my site, but it was fixed by wrapping everything in

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    // code
});
```

and using jQuery noConflict mode. I implemented that here (as you can see in the code), but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me, in WP I always use jQuery instead noConflict mode, 
Try to run this code: http://jsfiddle.net/GKmvA/1/

Comment: I just tried that and it unfortunately did not work.

Comment: could you post here what FireBug (or Chrome Inspector) said? Do you see eny error? Put <code>alert('It works');</code> before JS-code. Do you see alert after page refresh?

Comment: Sorry, I should've done that. I'll edit my original post, but it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ` on line 175. Line 175 is `var rows = 1;`, but WordPress autoformats it to display a `</p>` after the line (so `var rows = 1;</p>`). After removing all of the whitespace and linking it as a .js file (instead of directly embedding), it now works. Thank you!